# Is google maps JS library polyfilling Symbol

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6, polyfills

I have an app that has a script tag pulling in the google maps javascript library.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
v=3.exp&libraries=geometry&client=MY_CLIENT"></script>
```

I tried to pull out the script tag because i no longer needed it, and noticed weird behavior in non-map related code when running on an older version of chrome (chrome 30).

I have code that is checking if an es6 symbol is used as a key on an object

```
//mySymbol = Sybmol('whatever');
//...

if(mySymbol in obj){ //always returns true in old browsers without google maps loaded
  //do something
}
```

Before I removed the google maps script tag, this was functioning correctly. However, after I removed the script, the in operator began returning true for every symbol (even if it was not used on the object). I was able to consistently switch the behavior purely by adding the script tag back to my index.html and refreshing the page.

```
var foo = Symbol('foo')
var obj = {}
foo in obj //true if google maps is not loaded. false otherwise
```

This behavior is consistent with the polyfill limitations described [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#caveats-when-using-symbol-polyfill) and [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6010). But what confuses me is why I can't find any documentation of this polyfill in google maps' documentation, and why they are able to get around the polyfill limitations. Is this a known feature/behavior of google maps' js code?

Comment: By any chance would you be able to replicate this in an isolated way like in a jsfiddle or jsbin? No need to actually put in your credentials. I noticed you are also using clientID, would you have a Premium Plan with Google Maps APIs?

Comment: @henrisycip the repro is in the original message. it's the three line thing creating the foo symbol. The hard part though is running in an old browser. But anyone can just copy that to whatever browser they are running.

Comment: oh sorry i see. you mean with the google map script. i can add it

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior as well, and is breaking another library that expects Symbols not to be polyfilled.

Comment: i've been trying to reproduce it outside of my app and have been unable to.